# jqgrid horizontal scrollbar is missing if i search using filter toolbar

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

i am following the demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FrozenColumnsAndFilterToggle.htm given by oleg.

If i try to search using the filter bar with a criteria for which no data is available then horizontal scrollbar is disappearing.

steps to reproduce:

1. open the link
   http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FrozenColumnsAndFilterToggle.htm
   or http://jsfiddle.net/giganticuser/Pvsxp/2/
2. click on filter button in the footer of grid
3. type "asdf" in first column

[image: screenshot]

you will see the horizontal scroll bar disappearing.
can anybody suggest how to make sure horizontal scroll bar doesn't get disappear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following CSS style rules as a work-around:

```
table.ui-jqgrid-btable tr.jqgfirstrow td { border: none; }
table.ui-jqgrid-btable { height: 1px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pvsxp/5/

This will prevent the table containing your data from rendering at 0 height so that it will reserve its width even when there are no rows to display. You may also try setting the table's display property to block or inline-block to see whether that will work without the height rule.

Comment: Thanks RoccoC5. That worked for me on demo page. i will try it on my dev version where it has additional css customizaion and let u know.. thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

I used for alternative way of RoccoC5's solution.
It was helped following code.

```
table.ui-jqgrid-btable tr.jqgfirstrow td{border-color:#fff}
table.ui-jqgrid-btable{height:1px}
```

I changed border color to jqGrid's background color.

Thanks RoccoC5.